# Не срабатывает медиа запрос

Tags: html, css, css3, media-queries

На дисплеях меньше 768px блок меню должен исчезать

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.wrapper {
  width:100%;
  background: #1C1C1C;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: '.';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

.menu {
  float: right;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  transition:.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Menu</title>
    <link href = "style.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "wrapper">

      <div class = "menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Download</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class = "burger">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>

      <div class = "mobile-menu">
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не знаю, как у вас не работает, у меня, все работает.

Comment: Проверил, работает. Просто до этого я проверял через google chrome device toolbar, не срабатывало, но если уменьшать окно браузера все работает. Спасибо.